# How to draw straight line cross element showing determinant calculation

Tags: matrices, mathjax

I am working on MathJax.

```
$
\begin{array}{|ccc|cc}
1 & 2 &4 & 1 &2\\
3& 1 & 2 & 3 & 1\\
2 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 4\\
\end{array} = (0 + 8 + 48) - ( 8 + 8 + 0) = 40
$
```

[image: Question :]

I want crossing lines to show how to calculate the determinant of my matrix. I do not know how to call it in English.

Could somebody give me a hint or sample please?

Comment: Welcome! I'm afraid that questions about MathJax are off-topic here as MathJax does not actually have anything to do with TeX but only implements a subset of LaTeX syntax in a completely independent way.

Comment: Oh! sorry sorry. I did not know about deep details before. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: No problem. The fact that the site has a `mathjax` tag shows you just how common it is to ask questions about it here! (And obviously the existence of the tag can't help but suggest that it *is* on-topic. So there's a kind of cycle, I think.)