# How can I add cross line in determinant?

Tags: tex-core, mathjax

I am working with TeX via Mathjax. How can I make the determinant looks like the picture I have attached.

```
\begin{array}{|ccc|cc}
1 & 2 &4 & 1 &2\\
3& 1 & 2 & 3 & 1\\
2 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 4\\
\end{array} = (0 + 8 + 48) - ( 8 + 8 + 0) = 40
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApAm4.png]

Comment: Since MathJax has nothing to do with latex, other than it can understand some of the syntax, a question specific to MathJax is thus off topic on this site.

Comment: This question is remarkably similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288659/how-to-draw-straight-line-cross-element-showing-determinant-calculation, which was also closed as off topic.